# CSS animation in Windows 8.1 application not working

Tags: css, animation, windows-8, windows-8.1, winjs

I have a CSS animation inside of an application we're working on that was working before we started upgrading it to Windows 8.1. It is a relatively simple rotation transform that intended to make an image spin. The below is our CSS which seems valid and runs fine in IE11 with a test page.

```
.spinner img {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out nothing was wrong with the animation declaration itself, as expected. We had just wrapped the `keyframes` definition inside of a media query. Apparently, even though the media query was valid and was being correctly applied, neither IE11 nor Windows 8.1 would render the animation.

Long story short, moving the `keyframes` definition outside of the media query resolved the issue.